# UNION producing duplicates in output (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to compare UNION vs UNION ALL in MySQL Workbench. I am combining two tables that are not identical (hence the NULL AS column names) with UNION. However, I am getting a duplicate, and therefore UNION ALL and UNION are producing the same outputs. I know that the purpose of UNION vs UNION ALL is that UNION is supposed to only report unique values and not include duplicates in the output, but it is not doing that for me. Thank you for the help.

```
    SELECT
    e.emp_no,
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    NULL AS dept_no,
    NULL AS from_date
    FROM
    employees_dup AS e
    WHERE
    e.emp_no = 10001
    UNION SELECT
    NULL AS emp_no,
    NULL AS first_name,
    NULL AS last_name,
    m.dept_no,
    m.from_date
    FROM
    dept_manager AS m;
```

link to screenshot of code and output
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vpii.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any duplicates in the sample you gave. Yes, there are a lot of rows with the same value for department numbers but they all have different from dates. A union filters out duplicate rows, not values. You can have a list of twenty names all with the last name Smith. But Brain Smith and Carl Smith are clearly different names.

Comment: @PaulHerber Hey thanks for answering! I completely forgot I asked this question, but I believe I was referring to the first two rows of the output. However, I just realized it cause I have two names are "Georgi" and "George' haha! I assume I made a mistake inserting a new record or something like that. Thanks for taking the time to answer this silly question anyways